# delete image file from folder in server using php

Tags: php

How can i delete image file in my server folder called (images) using php i am trying the following code

```
<a href="delete.php? id=<?php echo $row_DetailRS1['id'];?>">Delete</a>
```

this take me to delete.php page

```
$id=$_GET['id'];            
$select = mysql_query("SELECT `file_name` FROM `flie_record WHERE `file_records`.`id` = '$id'");
$image  =mysql_fetch_array($select);
@unlink('images/'.$image);
```

nothing happening

Comment: you're trying to unlink an array... RTLM: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array then also go read up about [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com) before you get your server pwn3d.

Comment: ... and the `@` makes sure you don't see the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$image` is an array and you need to add the key:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];            
$select = mysql_query("SELECT `file_name` FROM `file_records` WHERE `file_records`.`id` = '$id'");
$image  =mysql_fetch_array($select);
@unlink('images/'.$image['file_name']);
```

and `(int)` to `$_GET['id']` - integer for MySQL injection hole.

Comment: @MihaiIorga thanks for answer, when is used the above code still nothing happened when i echo ('images/'.$image['file_name']); result is: images/ so its not taking file name.

Comment: @webdevelopersana take the code above again. I've updated.. you misspelled `file_records` on select

Comment: @MihaiIorga you are php genius. Thanks you all